# C#: Why can I convert only 999 chars to 1024 bytes?

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion, byte

```
string longMessage = "";//The string to convert to bytes
for (int i = 0; i < 999; i++)//Adding 999 chars
{
    longMessage += "i";
}
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];//Array of bytes to store the message
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
formatter.Serialize(stream, longMessage);
```

Why do I get an error while I put more than 999 chars in the string, and not after 1024 chars? I get the following error:

> NotSupportedException: Cannot expand this MemoryStream

ERROR: Without this type information it wouldn't know that to what actual type it should deserialize back.

Comment: Did you forget to give us the actual error information?  I don't feel like guessing what's going on.

Comment: @rory.ap NotSupportedException: Cannot expand this MemoryStream

Comment: Please edit your actual question to include this information.  I don't know why you wouldn't have included that to begin with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string itself has an Encoding - it's not just an array of 1 byte characters. It contains additional information about that string and how to read it (ASCII, Unicode, UTF etc.).

You can use the following to use ASCII encoding to get a 1024 byte array from the input string:

```
string longMessage = "";//The string to convert to bytes
for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)//Adding 1024 chars
{
    longMessage += "i";
}
byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(longMessage);
```

Comment: @Aviv Yes, UTF-16, just like all strings in .NET, Java, JavaScript, XML, HTML,…. If you want text with mainly Western scripts to be more compact (at the cost of taking more space for text in Eastern scripts), use `buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(longMessage)`. If you want silent data loss, go ahead and use ASCII. In any case, Serialization and deserialization routines must use the same encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `BinaryFormatter` emits type information in addition to the actual data. This means that there are additional bytes indicating that you are storing strings. In the version of the .NET framework that you are using (because the BinaryFormatter is not portable) apparently this type information occupies 25 bytes.

Without this type information it wouldn't know that to what actual type it should deserialize back.

So basically you could let it take as much bytes as needed for the binary serialization:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(stream, longMessage);
    byte[] actualData = stream.ToArray();
}
```